# Set download limit and expiry for WooCommerce downloadable products in specific categories

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following code that set a global download limit and expiry, for all WooCommerce downloadable products:

```
//FOR VARIATION DOWNLOADABLE PRODUCTS

 // set 3 downloads for all variation downloadable products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_download_limit', function ($val, $obj) {
    return $val <= 0 ? 3 : $val;
}, 30, 2);

 // set 3 days expiration for all variation downloadable products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_download_expiry', function ($val, $obj) {
    return $val <= 0 ? 3 : $val;
}, 30, 2);


//FOR SIMPLE DOWNLOADABLE PRODUCTS

 // set 3 downloads for all simple downloadable products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_download_limit', function ($val, $obj) {
    return $val <= 0 ? 3 : $val;
}, 30, 2);

// set 3 days expiration for all simple downloadable products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_download_expiry', function ($val, $obj) {
    return $val <= 0 ? 3 : $val;
}, 30, 2);
```

**MY PROBLEM:**
I don't want to set the download limit and expiry **globally** (for **all** downloadable products), but **only for specific product categories** instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if you want to set the download limit based on the user type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WordPress conditional function `has_term()` to target specific product categories this way:

```php
// Set a different Download limit for specific downloadable products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_download_limit', 'product_get_download_limit_filter_callback', 30, 2 ); // Simple
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_download_limit', 'product_get_download_limit_filter_callback', 30, 2 ); // Variation
function product_get_download_limit_filter_callback( $value, $product ) {
    $categories = array( 'action', 'adventure' ); // <== HERE define your product categories (terms ids, slugs or names)

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && $value <= 0 ) {
        $value = 3;
    }
    return $value;
}

// Set a different Download expiration for specific downloadable products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_download_expiry', 'product_get_download_expiry_filter_callback', 30, 2 ); // Simple
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_download_expiry', 'product_get_download_expiry_filter_callback', 30, 2 ); // Variation
function product_get_download_expiry_filter_callback( $value, $product ) {
    $categories = array( 'action', 'adventure' ); // <== HERE define your product categories (terms ids, slugs or names)

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && $value <= 0 ) {
        $value = 3;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.